# Node.js: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE in HTTP2 client

Tags: node.js, http2

When I am trying to connect to the local HTTP2 server as listed here: [HTTP2 Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_server_side_example)

I am getting the following error:

> { Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: unable to verify the first certificate)
>       at ClientHttp2Session.destroy (internal/http2/core.js:1175:20)
>       at TLSSocket.socketOnError (internal/http2/core.js:2515:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>       cause:
>          { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>          at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
>          at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>          at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8) code: 
>       'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } }

Comment: This is error is showing its require `SSL` certificate and in doc it seems you cannot create server without certificate.

Comment: The server is working ok, I used the valid HTTPS certificates.

Comment: I am getting this error in the HTTP2 client.

Comment: Can you show me the code ?

Comment: client = http2.connect(process.env.API_URL, {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
  })

Comment: cert.crt is the same file used in the server.